# Why is this submit form not working?

Tags: php

In the following code, everything works except that when you click the submit button, nothing happens at all

Please tell me what's wrong, the connection and everything is fine (it is included in the Header.php file) and submit forms on other pages work, but this one seems to just do nothing, page doesn't even load

Thanks!

Here is the code

```
<?php

//connection is in header
include "../Header.php";
//checks if logged in
if (!$User)
{
header("Location: ../index.php"); exit();
}
//heres the form
echo"<form><center><br /><br /><br /><br /><font size='3'><br />You are changing your Post Color<br />
Your current color is $myU->PostColor<br /><br /></font><form>
Color:<br /><textarea name='color' rows='1' cols='15'></textarea><br /><br />
<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='submit'></form></center></form>";

$Color = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['Color']));
$submit = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['submit']));



if ($submit) {

mysqli_query("UPDATE `socialli_main`.`Users` SET `PostColor` = '$Color' WHERE `Users`.`ID` ='$myU->ID'");

header("Location: ../index.php"); exit();
}



include "../Footer.php";
```

Comment: missing some basic html such as `<forrm>`

Comment: And please don't use `<center>`.

Comment: Also use mysqli api. mysql is deprecated in newest version of php

Comment: I know lol, I just didn't want to include my css here (don't worry, I used float center and font-size)

Comment: You don't need to echo everything. Just close the code with ?> and type your HTML. Well you should not mix code and templates but at least...

Comment: Thanks for all the tips guys, added all of them, but still haven't gotten my main question answered

Comment: post the new code you are using

Comment: I edited it showing the new code

Comment: `<form>` is missing a few things

Comment: I have it in my code I am using but forgot to add it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A submit button will submit the form that it is inside. You don't have a `<form>` element at all. You need to add one.

Comment: No luck but added it anyway, it made it so it atleast submits, problem is the SQL I believe now

Comment: @user2977179 Try what I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

More importantly than adding a `<form>` tag is actually setting attributes on it. Try the following.

```
<form action='' method='POST'>
```

And you also end your `</form>` tag many times...

Here is how I would fix up your code anyways:

```
<?php
    //connection is in header
    include "../Header.php";

    //checks if logged in
    if (!$User)
        header("Location: ../index.php"); exit();
?>
<form action='' method='POST'>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        <span style="font-size:1.6em;">
            You are changing your Post Color
        </span><br>
        <span style="font-size:1.3em;">
            Your current color is <?=$myU->PostColor?>
        </span><br>
        Color:<br />
            <textarea name='color' rows='1' cols='15'></textarea>
        <br /><br />
        <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='submit'>
    </div>
</form>
<?php
    $Color = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['Color']));
    $submit = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['submit']));

    if ($submit){
        mysqli_query("UPDATE `socialli_main`.`Users` SET `PostColor` = '$Color' WHERE `Users`.`ID` ='$myU->ID'");
        header("Location: ../index.php"); exit();
    }
include "../Footer.php";
?>
```

Comment: I tried, worked, but I got this error

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_query() in /home/socialli/public_html/Account/PostColor.php on line 24

Comment: Changed it to MySQL_query, now it works just have to fix the SQL now, thanks!

Comment: @user2977179 No Problem! I also edited my answer to show you how to clean up your code.